# Searching through two for loops without repeating the result.

Tags: arraylist

I have a task where I am trying to check an array list of "jobs" against an array list of "machines" (all different types) and if the first three letters off the job match the first three letters off the machine (e.g. a PRT job code could only be assigned to a machine with code PRT). I want it to accept the job but if not I would like it to print out a message saying that there is no available machine. I have only been learning Java for a couple of weeks so this might not be the best way:

```
public void assignJob() {
    for(Job j : jobs) {
            String jobCode = j.getCode().substring(0, 3);
            for(Machine m : machines) {
                String machineCode = m.getCode().substring(0,3); 
                 if (jobCode.equals(machineCode)){
                    m.acceptJob(j);
                    System.out.println("The job " + j.getCode() + " has been 
assigned to a machine.");
                    break;
                }

            else {          
            System.out.println("Sorry there is no machine available to accept the type of job: " + j.getCode() );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I am getting is that it is printing out the message every time it goes around the loop so it will say there is no machine available 3 times before it finds the correct machine the fourth time and then says the job has been accepted. I only really want the message one time and only after it has searched and not found anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean found = false; above the outer for loop, move else part of if statement below the outer for loop and make it an if statement. If you've found your match then set found = true; and break loops. Then check if it is found, display message if not found...